# How can I create independent TestNG Maven executable

Tags: java, maven, jar, testng, war

I need to create a .jar file using **maven** and **testng**.
My jar needs to read a testng.xml file and execute all the tests that are in there.
I tried `maven-shade-plugin` and created a jar, but when i try to execute it i have the error:`Could not find or load main class org.testng.TestNG`.
I tried to solve this problem finding a lot of solutions suggesting to create classpath but i fear this is not what i need. My jar file will be uploaded in a server and it will have to be executed from there, i can't create a classpath on that server, i need an independent file.
i can use some workarounds if thery are able to do this task (war file, exe file, etc...)

My tests are under the `src/test/java` path.
My POM:

```
<repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>jcenter</id>
            <name>bintray</name>
            <url>https://jcenter.bintray.com</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>shade</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <transformers>
                                <transformer
                                    implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                                    <mainClass>org.testng.TestNG</mainClass>
                                </transformer>
                            </transformers>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

Comment: Why not executing the test during the build? Why generating a jar file via maven-shade-plugin?

Comment: i was asked to provide only the jar files

Comment: Sorry but that does not make sense... The test can run during the build... That's it...

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64963846/5324105 this may help

Comment: this is not working :(

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar requirement long time back.  You would need to create a jar with all dependencies. I had written up the process I followed [here](https://niharikawhatsnext.wordpress.com/2015/03/11/running-maven-testng-tests-as-a-jar/).   HTH.

Comment: [ERROR] Could not find goal 'test-jar' in plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-assembly-plugin:2.5.3 among available goals assembly, attached, directory, directory-inline, directory-single, help, single, unpack -> [Help 1]